# Difference between "прах" and "пепел"

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

Is there any significant difference between the nouns **прах** and **пепел**. I understand they both refer to *ashes*, but are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 14):

*Прах* is remains of a dead human body, not necessarily cremated  (мир праху его). The word is a little bookish and almost not used in everyday language.

*Пепел* is remains of any burnt thing (бумажный пепел, пепел костра). See also *зола*.

Answer (score 11):

I agree with Alex.S that first thing one think of hearing word "прах" nowadays is what is left of a man after his death. "Прах к праху" is a citation from Bible - "Ashes to ashes". However this is high-style figurative meaning. And it is the only time when "ashes" is translated as "прах".

In fact "прах" is old word for "dust", and not for a "пепел". Пепел is what is left from burnt things.

Below go examples from [Ushakov's dictionary](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1101158).

1. Usages of "прах" in "dust" meaning: "Отрясти прах от ног" - remove dust from feet. "Прах вился столбом" (Лермонтов) - "Dust was raised high".
2. Another old-style figurative meaning - something non-valuable, "И мощь бесов исчезнет яко прах" (Пушкин) - "Devils' might will disappear like dust", "Деньги прах, вот что я тебе говорю" (Островский) - "Money is a dust, that's what I'm saying to you". (However if I would translate this to English I would use "ashes" to make a reference to Bible).
3. Finally - dead body (figurative), including cremated body (in this case it is less figurative - instead of "ashes" you call this powder "a dust").
4. And there are several proverbs "В пух и в прах" - completely, like when spent all money on gambling - "проигрался в пух и в прах", "Пойти прахом" - when something valuable is ruined or disappeared, like when someone's business was ruined because of a bankrupcy.

So, as a bottom line, these words are usually not interchangeable. They are interchangeable only in biblical figurative meaning, or when you are referring to a cremated body.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! So, when people talk about having their ashes scattered over the ocean when they die, I assume both прах and пепел can be used?

Comment: Yes, both words are used when referring to scattering cremated remains.

Comment: @CocoPop yes, exactly. It is literally пепел, and it is metaphorically прах of a late person in biblical sense.

Answer (score 6):

"*Прах*" (Church Slavonic), "*порох*" (native Russian) and "*порошок*" (diminutive of "порох") were essentially the same thing, but in modern language they have become completely different: "порох" - gunpowder, "порошок" - any powder, except gunpowder and cosmetic powder (which is denoted by the loanword "пудра"), and for "прах" now remain only bookish and high-style figurative expressions for dust and human ashes.

"*Пепел*" is a cognate word to "powder", yet it denotes exclusively a light powder-like ash (often flying round the fire). As such ash is typically grayish, so there is an adjective "*пепельный*" which means "grayish color" (e.g. "пепельные волосы").

On the other hand, "*зола*" (btw. it's a cognate to "coal") means dark heavy ash, which usually remains in the fireplace.

Comment: So, basically `пепел` vs. `зола` is "ash" vs. "cinder", am I right?

Comment: @OlegLobachev Also remember that **Cinder**ella = **Зол**ушка ;-) However, the differences between all these words are very slight, so there's no 100% right answer.